Undesired Histidine Residue Introduced by NdeI Cleavage Site: Seeking Optimization Strategies
I'm currently working on a genetic engineering project where I aim to insert my gene of interest into a vector downstream of a TEV cleavage site. The vector is designed to be cut with the NdeI restriction enzyme, but unfortunately, the NdeI recognition site also encodes an additional histidine amino acid. I'm concerned that this extra histidine residue might interfere with the function of my protein.
I'm seeking advice on how to address this issue. I would greatly appreciate any suggestions or recommendations.


Is the His residue really an issue? Do you expect it to affect the protein any more than the TEV site and whatever other tag you have upstream of it, and what appears to be a T7 tag downstream of it?
If there absolutely cannot be a His, the easiest and cheapest solution would probably just be ordering a synthetic gene with the exact sequence that you want. When you can get a gene cloned into an expression vector, sequence verified, and shipped to you for $150 USD, is fiddling around with restriction digests and ligation reactions really worth the effort?

I'm not concerned about the residues before the TEV site, as they will be cleaved off after the TEV protease cuts, leaving only the terminal amino acid. I'm also using overlapping oligos for the synthetic gene. Given my current resources, I'm looking to develop a vector system where the gene is placed immediately after the TEV site, thus avoiding any additional amino acids between the TEV site and the gene

Oh yeah, of course the TEV site is cleaved, how stupid of me. Would a scarless cloning method like Gibson assembly work? Alternatively, if your gene always starts with the T7 tag (Met-Ala-Ser…), can you include this sequence in the vector and use NheI for cloning? This assumes you have some control over the vector sequence. Your vector would be …TCCATGG|CTAGC…
